# JavaScript returns value on the first review only, l don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, django

Am having a problem but l nor know what brings it.

When I try to loop the Django to for JavaScript to display the Stars,  it returns only on the first review and the rest it returns nothing.

**Now what can't do so that each user who adds a rating it displays it's stars not displaying only the first one?**

Below it's my **HTML** and **JavaScript**  below

Even l added also an image for results if try to reflesh the page.

**Html**

```
 {% for review in reviews %}
   <p>display of numbers </p>
   <option value="{{ review.rating }}" id="hours"></option>
<div class="staz">
<p id="demo"></p>
{% endfor %}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    let hour = document.getElementById('hours').value;
    let greetings;
        if (hour == 1){
            greetings = "★";
        }
        else if (hour == 2){
            greetings = "★★"
        }
        else if(hour == 3){
            greetings = "★★★"
        }
        else if(hour == 4){
            greetings = "★★★★"
        }
        else if(hour == 5){
            greetings = "★★★★★";
        }
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = greetings
</script>
```

**Results**

[image: image showing the results if l try to reload the page]

I expected that each review, it returns it's stars.

Comment: `id`s must be unique within a document. You're outputting several elements with `id="demo"` in a loop, only the first of which will be used when selecting an element by id.

Comment: Now how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `id` to `class` then using  `querySelectorAll` get all element which has `hours` class and assign required star to div .

So, your `django` code will be change to :

```
{% for review in reviews %}
 <!--...some codes added class here -->
   <option value="{{ review.rating }}" class="hours"></option>
<div class="staz">
<p class="demo"></p> <!--added class here -->
{% endfor %}
```

***Demo Code*** :

```js
const hours_div = document.querySelectorAll('.hours');
hours_div.forEach(function(item) {
  var hour = item.value;
  var greetings = ''
  if (hour == 1) {
    greetings = "★";
  } else if (hour == 2) {
    greetings = "★★"
  } else if (hour == 3) {
    greetings = "★★★"
  } else if (hour == 4) {
    greetings = "★★★★"
  } else if (hour == 5) {
    greetings = "★★★★★";
  }
  item.nextElementSibling.children[0].innerHTML = greetings
})
```

```html
<p>display of numbers </p>
<option value="4" class="hours"></option>
<div class="staz">
  <p class="demo"></p>
</div>

<p>display of numbers </p>
<option value="3" class="hours"></option>
<div class="staz">
  <p class="demo"></p>
</div>

<p>display of numbers </p>
<option value="2" class="hours"></option>
<div class="staz">
  <p class="demo"></p>
</div>

<p>display of numbers </p>
<option value="1" class="hours"></option>
<div class="staz">
  <p class="demo"></p>
</div>
```